# nextjs api not working when fetching through isomorphic-unfetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, next.js, isomorphic-fetch-api

Im not getting my data **(notes)** inside the props, it is giving undefined when im using console.log(notes).
My backend api is also in the same project in /pages/api/notes/index.js
The api which im calling is 'http://localhost:3000/api/notes'

[image]

**Even my api is working fine when im testing it on postman. But on the frontend, data isnt available**

[image]

**Please checkout this issue.**

Comment: I also think it's worth noting that since NextJs 9.4 fetch has been polyfilled such that you don't need ```isomorphic-unfetch```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you simply have a typo. `Index.getinitialProps` should be `Index.getInitialProps`. Note that the "i" in initial is capitalized.

Also as a tip, you don't explicitly need `http://localhost:3000`, if you just call it with `/api/notes` it will correctly resolve the request. That way when you deploy the app you don't have to go back and make a ton of changes for your data fetches.